# Implementing tornado.locks.Lock over multiple processes

Tags: python, tornado

I've been thinking about how I can implement tornado locks over multiple processes.

I have multiple processes that have the same co-routines. I never want C2 to run while C1 is running or vice versa (even across processes)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can implement this using the tornado.locks.Lock?

```
p1     p2     p3

C1     C1     C1


C2     C2     C2
```

### EDIT

I've been reading about multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager I started a server then in my tornado **init** i tried to connect to it with:

```
  m = SyncManager(address=("", 50000), authkey=b'abc')
  m.connect()
```

I then acquired a lock with:

```
check=lock.acquire(blocking=False)
```

I started another tornado process and did the same thing. However the Lock() class creates a separate instance for each process... How do i share this same object over multiple processes?

Comment: You need to add more detail. What do you mean by "multiple processes" - do you mean multiple tornado IO loops?

Comment: Yes, multiple tornado processes all running their own IOLoop. However I need one external place for locking that will work across all processes to control the co-routines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with `tornado.lock.Lock`; this is a single-process synchronization primitive (and it doesn't know anything about the `multiprocessing` `SyncManager`. You could use `SyncManager.Lock` to get a multi-process lock, but it's synchronous so you can't easily use it from an async Tornado app).

You'll need to talk to some external coordinating process to handle locking across multiple processes, and even then you'll have to handle the possibility that a process dies while holding the lock (so you need to allow for locks to expire somehow, and handle the case where the lock expires while the process holding it is not actually dead...). I recommend using something like `etcd` or ZooKeeper as your locking service.

Comment: Hi Ben thanks for your response it's much appreciated. I will look into your recommendations. However I ended up solving the issues with the below code I'm not sure if that poses some of the synchronous issues you state in your answer?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for recommending me etcd it's exactly what i needed :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ben thanks for your above response. I ended up using the Lock from:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
```

In my `main()` I instantiate the `Lock()` and spawn a new process which starts the tornado server. I pass the lock (l) and then store it within the tornado application:

```
if __name__ =='__main__':
   l=Lock()
   Process(target=runServer,args=(l,8000)).start()
   Process(target=runServer,args=(l,8001)).start()


def runServer(lock,port):
      app=Application(lock,port)
      # start tornado server here

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
   def __init__(self,lock,port):

      # Store the lock
      self.lock=lock
```

I have some co-routines that rely on waiting for this lock to become free E.g. Within a co-routine I have the following:

```
        while (not self.lock.acquire(block=False)):
           yield tornado.gen.sleep(.01)
```

I understand your point around if one of the processes goes down and will need to deal with this case. This seems to work or do you see other problems with this approach to do with async and what i'm doing?

Thank

Comment: Yeah, this should work, it's just less convenient and efficient to acquire the lock (since if it's not available immediately you have to wait at least 10ms, and then keep waking up every 10ms while the other process is working).